# Rails 3: request is redirected to https even after giving config.force_ssl set to false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

my http request is redirected to https even after giving `config.force_ssl` set to false. I am getting  `"rack.url_scheme"=>"https", "HTTPS"=>"on"`in request object.

Comment: Have you restarted your server? Have you set this option in right env config file?

Comment: Are you calling `force_ssl` in any controller?

Comment: No, I searched force_ssl everywhere in application but it only mentioned in production.rb